# Is there any affiliate extension for magento 2?

Tags: magento2, affiliate

Is there any affiliate extension for magento 2

Comment: you would have got your answer just by a simple google search

Comment: visit cedcommerce and chat with support team other wise search on google.com. you can find better extension for your magento store.